# Module of differentials of a tensor of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

Fix a base ring $A$. I am looking at Lemma 6.1.11 in Liu.

> Let $B_1, B_2$ be $A$-algebras, $R = B_1 \otimes_A B_2$. Then there is a canonical isomorphism
> $$ \varphi: (\Omega_{B_1 / A} \otimes_{B_1} R) \oplus (\Omega_{B_2/A} \otimes _{B_2} R) \to \Omega _{R/A}$$
> given by $(db_1 \otimes r_1 ) + (db_2 \otimes r_2) \mapsto r_1 d(b_1 \otimes 1) + r_2 d(1 \otimes b_2)$
> [image]

This is all he says about the proof.

What does it mean to say $\varphi_i$ is a section of $\psi_i$? How do the two exact sequences give that $\varphi = \varphi_1 \oplus \varphi_2$ is an isomorphism?

Since this isn't a left-exact sequence, we don't even have injections of $\varphi_i$ separately. I am not convinced that the sum would be injective. However, if somehow the sequences were short-exact, I would surmise that one combines the sequences to give a splitting and therefore, an isomorphism that decomposes as Liu claims.